# Backintime intermittent brand new scan

Tags: 22.04, backintime

I have been using Backintime for years. I just updated to Ubuntu Server 22.04.

After performing the initial scan (which takes an hour) it is now, alternately, performing a scan for just the updates (takes less than 1 minute) and a full scan.  What this looks like is this:

- I have Backintime scheduled to run every day at 8 a.m.
- After the initial scan after install, on day 1, it took 1 minute.
- Day 2, it took an hour.
- Day 3, one minute.

This isn't how it worked before.  After the initial scan after install, each scheduled scan only took 1 minute.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what might be causing this?